# DBCP - PSQL Exception - Connection Pool

Tags: java, postgresql, unit-testing, jdbc, connection-pooling

I get a problem with my unit test. I am trying to realise some unit test to check database request (insert, update, parse, bind, execute...).

Thing is that I get the following exception:

> PSQLException : This connection has been closed.

My code :

The DataSource class to be able to use same connection in different class

```
public class DataSource {

    private static DataSource     datasource;
    private BasicDataSource ds;

    private DataSource() throws IOException, SQLException, PropertyVetoException {
        ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        ds.setUsername("postgres");
        ds.setPassword("postgres");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ehealth");

     // the settings below are optional -- dbcp can work with defaults
     //   ds.setMinIdle(5);
     //   ds.setMaxIdle(20);
     //   ds.setMaxOpenPreparedStatements(180);

    }

    public static DataSource getInstance() throws IOException, SQLException, PropertyVetoException {
        if (datasource == null) {
            datasource = new DataSource();
            return datasource;
        } else {
            return datasource;
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return this.ds.getConnection();
    }

}
```

My static method which returns a map of `<String, List<PreparedStatement>>`

```
public static Map<String, List<PreparedStatement>> test(int numberOfRequest) throws SQLException{
        try(Connection con = getHealthConnection(); Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, 
                ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY, 
                ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT);){
            Map<String, List<PreparedStatement>> myMap = new HashMap<String, List<PreparedStatement>>();
            List<PreparedStatement> lstPreparedStmt = new ArrayList<PreparedStatement>();
            String request = "INSERT INTO PATIENT VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, 'M', 'OTHER')";
            myMap.put(request, null);
            int counter = 0;
            String rqstSelect = "SELECT * FROM patient ORDER BY pat_id"; //initialize SELECT request
            ResultSet resRequest = stmt.executeQuery(rqstSelect); //execute SELECT
            String newId = createNewIdByIncrement(resRequest); //initialize first new id
            while(counter < numberOfRequest){
                String newName = generateRandomString(); //generate random new name
                String newLast = generateRandomString(); //generate random new last name
                String newLast2 = generateRandomString(); //generate random new last name 2
                PreparedStatement prep = con.prepareStatement(request, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                        ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY,
                        ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT);
                prep.setString(1, newId);
                prep.setString(2, newName);
                prep.setString(3, newLast);
                prep.setString(4, newLast2);
                lstPreparedStmt.add(prep);
                counter = counter + 1; //increment counter
                int newIdAsInt = Integer.parseInt(newId) + 1; //increment id
                newId = concatenationZeroIntAsString(newIdAsInt, 8);
            }
            myMap.put(request, lstPreparedStmt);
            return myMap;
        }
    }
```

To finish, method which is called by my @Test which share same connection which previous method called

```
private void insertPreparedStatementRequest(int numberOfRequest) throws SQLException, IOException, PropertyVetoException{
        try(Connection con = DataSource.getInstance().getConnection(); Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, 
                ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY, 
                ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT);){    
            // check number of row before insert
            String rqstCountRowBefore = "SELECT * FROM patient ORDER BY pat_id";
            ResultSet resCheckBefore = stmt.executeQuery(rqstCountRowBefore);
            int rowBefore = TestUtils.getRowCount(resCheckBefore);
            Assert.assertNotNull("Request's result is null", resCheckBefore);
            // insert X row
            Map<String, List<PreparedStatement>> allRequest = TestUtils.test(numberOfRequest);
            for(Map.Entry<String, List<PreparedStatement>> e : allRequest.entrySet()){
                List<PreparedStatement> lstStatement = e.getValue();
                Iterator<PreparedStatement> valIterator = lstStatement.iterator();
                while(valIterator.hasNext()){
                    valIterator.next().execute();
                }
            }
            // check number of row after insert
            String rqstCountrowAfter = "SELECT * FROM patient ORDER BY pat_id";
            ResultSet resCheckAfter = stmt.executeQuery(rqstCountrowAfter);
            int rowAfter = TestUtils.getRowCount(resCheckAfter);
            Assert.assertNotNull("Request's result is null", resCheckBefore);
            Assert.assertEquals("Insert result's request unsuccesfull", rowBefore + numberOfRequest, rowAfter);
        }
    }
```

I don't understand why my connection seems to be closed. I need to get same connection in this last method than in the first one. Thing is that I created a DataSource to use the connection already created in the first method.

The error came from this line : `valIterator.next().execute()`

LOGS :

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.checkClosed(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:714)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.getAutoCommit(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:680)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:507)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:381)
    at eu.clarussecure.proxy.protocol.plugins.pgsql.Scenarii.insertPreparedStatementRequest(Scenarii.java:191)
    at eu.clarussecure.proxy.protocol.plugins.pgsql.Scenarii.insertPreparedStmtPatientRow5(Scenarii.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: How are you cleaning up your data in the DB after each test? What does createNewIdByIncrement() function do exactly?

Comment: Actually there is no way to clean DB after Test. I will code it later (don't know how).
My client already get a DB and I am working on it. He doesn't now if he will set id column as auto increment. Then, in case, I already realise method to set Id (to realise my test) even if I sure it will auto increment

Comment: Blind bet: createNewIdByIncrement() is creating the same Ids on each run, but your table already has that values as primary keys. The INSERT fails and the try(Connection con = ...) { ... } closes the connection. Then you see the connection closed somewhere else, but it is unrelated to the apparent point of failure because the conection was closed before.

Comment: I use createNewIdByIncrement() in several other test and it's working fine. Don't think so it's the problem.
I tried to create only one method and put all method test() code in insertPreparedStatement() method. And evrything is working well.

Then problem came from connection. I need to create a connection pool (I believe). I don't know how to configure Name to bind() and lookup() my datasource. I am working with Postgres and I need to create a properties file maybe... I am a beginner with connection pool

Answer (score 0):

A `PreparedStatement` is a resource in the context of a specific `Connection`. In your `test` method, you have created prepared statements out of - `Connection con = getHealthConnection();` then you exit method - `test`.

Exiting `test` method will return connection to pool or close it but eventually you will not be able to get same `Connection` object unless you have implemented singleton on `Connection` which you don't so most likely `Connection` on which statements were created is closed after call to `test` is finished.

In your `insertPreparedStatementRequest` method , you are creating a new `Connection` and that connection object has nothing to do with connection object on which those statements were prepared hence the error.

You need to execute those prepared statements as long as underlying connection of those statements is alive. For that, you need to pass on Connection from your `insertPreparedStatementRequest` to `test` method i.e. `Connection` needs to be made external to `test` method.

Hope it helps !!

Comment: Ho! It appears really simple right now! Instead of create connection (which is closed at the end of test()), I could put these both methods in a other one (which initiate connection) and add Connection parameters.

Will try this, thank you very much mate!